# addClass removeClass jQuery problems with sliderhow

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is a link to the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Erw8y/18/).

Javascript:

```
var headerCount;
var timeDelay;
$(document).ready(function () {
  headerCount = $('.headerlink').length;
  timeDelay = $('.current').attr('ref');
  if (undefined != timeDelay) {
    timeDelay = "5000"
  }
  setTimeout("advance()", timeDelay);
});

function advance() {
  $('.current').next('.headerlink').addClass('current2');
  $('.current').removeClass("current");
  $('.current2').addClass('current').removeClass('current2');
  if (headerCount == $(".current").index('.headerlink')) {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.headerlink:nth-child(1)').addClass('current');
  }
  timeDelay = $('.current').attr('ref');
  if (undefined != timeDelay) {
    timeDelay = "5000"
  }
  setTimeout("advance()", timeDelay);
}​
```

HTML:

```
<a ref="5000" class="headerlink current" href="http://www.raceramps.com/12-4thqtr-twenty-five-dollar-rebate.aspx"> <img class="headerimg" src="http://www.raceramps.com/images/promos/4thQTR[25_rebateCheck].jpg" /> </a>

<a class="headerlink" href="http://www.raceramps.com/2012-3rdqtr-25-visa.aspx"> <img class="headerimg" src="http://www.raceramps.com/images/promos/3rdQTR[25VISA_rebate].jpg" /> </a>

<a class="headerlink" href="http://www.raceramps.com/12-4thqtr-twenty-five-dollar-rebate.aspx"> <img class="headerimg" src="http://www.raceramps.com/images/promos/4thQTR[25_rebateCheck].jpg" /> </a>

<a class="headerlink" href="http://www.raceramps.com/12-4thqtr-twenty-five-dollar-rebate.aspx"> <img class="headerimg" src="http://www.raceramps.com/images/promos/4thQTR[25_rebateCheck].jpg" /> </a>
```

**Problem:** The goal is for the code to add `.current` to the `next('.headerlink')`, then remove `.current` from the original. But for some reason, it just removes `.current` (it appears to add/remove to all the matching elements very quickly).

What am I missing?
    ​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

http://jsfiddle.net/carlosmartinezt/Erw8y/29/

The code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout("advance()", $('.current').attr('ref') || 1000);
});

function advance() {
  var nextHeaderLink = $('.current').removeClass("current").next('.headerlink');

  if( nextHeaderLink.length == 0 )
      nextHeaderLink = $('.headerlink:first-child');

  nextHeaderLink.addClass('current');

  setTimeout("advance()", nextHeaderLink.attr('ref') || 1000);
}​
```

It is a simplified version, removing irrelevant lines of code.

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly within your answer, ideally with some explanation of the changes made.  This answer should remain relevant if jsfiddle is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to have:

```
undefined == timeDelay
```

and not `!=`.

You are passing `undefined` as the duration of `setTimeout` causing it to execute immediately.

---

You can also simplify your code and remove the need for `current2` all together.

```
var $current = $('.current');
var $newCurrent = $current.next('.headerlink').addClass('current');

$current.removeClass('current'); // This still only has the first element even though you added .current to another
```

The trick is that the variable `$current` contains the element which matched its selector at the time it was created.  Subsequent changes to the DOM do not affect the set of matched elements in `$current`.

Full example with some additional cleanup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Erw8y/28/)